# Distributing $2$ identical balls to $8$ distinct boxes

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways to distribute $2$ identical balls to $8$ distinct boxes.

This is how I reasoned it:

As the boxes are distinct, the only way by which we could get different configurations would be by considering the number of ways in which $2$ distinct pairs of boxes can be chosen. This can be done in $\binom {8}{2} $ ways.

Do you think that I have reasoned it correctly?

Comment: But can one contain two balls

Comment: @KingTut so what do you think should the answer be ?

Comment: I was asking that can one box containg two balls? If yes then the answer would be $\binom{8}{2} + \binom{8}{1}$.

Comment: @KingTut okay ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: $C^{N-1}_{K-1}$ where N=8 and K=2.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer  The formula you are using is applied when at least one ball is placed in each box, which is not the case here.

Comment: @KingTut  You should convert your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by *"distribute"*:

a) if you mean  *"(randomly) throw the balls into the boxes"* , 
then it means that you consider equi-probable that at each launch you can 
choose one of the $8$ boxes, so a total of $8^2=64$ ways to do that;

b) if instead you mean  *"(randomly) pour the balls into the boxes"* , 
meaning that you consider equi-probable any "occupation histogram"
such as $(2,0, \cdots,0), \cdots,(1,1,0,\cdots,0), \cdots$, then that is equivalent to the 
number of [*weak* compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29)
 of $2$ into exactly $8$ parts, which is $\binom{2+8-1}{8-1} = 36$.